# Java : Replace \" with " and \/ with /

Tags: java, regex, json, gson, replaceall

I'm creating json string to send to the server. I use GSon to generate json string. Because my server doesn't understand string like: `\"key\":value` but `"key":value` or `"a\/b"` but `a/b`. So after generating json string, I use `replaceAll` method to fix this:

```
String res = original.replaceAll("\\/", "/").replaceAll("\\"", "\"");
```

But this method doesn't work as I expected. Please tell me how to replace string to conform with server as above.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. What you want to match: `\"`
2. A backslash is a regex special char (used to escape), so you need to escape them: `\\"`
3. A backslash is also a Java special char in strings (also used to escape), so you need to escape them: `\\\\"`
4. a double-quote needs to be escaped as well in Java (since it's the string literal delimiter): `\\\\\"`

You want to replace by a double-quote, so the point #4 needs to be applied again:

```
.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"")
```

Same logic for the other replacement (without the point #4 since no double-quote):

```
.replaceAll("\\\\/", "/")
```

Combined into one single regex:

```
.replaceAll("\\\\([\"/])", "$1")
```

Comment: @hqt: This answer is more elegant than mine, please consider accepting it instead.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes. spOOm solution is elegant, but not so intutive for newbie, but he has explained well how going to last point. just because you have posted first :D thanks for notice me :)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Java backslash hell:

```
String res = original.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"").replaceAll("\\\\/", "/");
```

In a regex, `\\` matches a single `\` character, and in a string (which you build the regex from), you need to write `"\\"` for every single literal `"\"`, so you need four backslashes for each actual backslash you want to match by regex.

It would be nice if Java had either a literal regex type (like Ruby, Perl or JavaScript) or a verbatim string type (like C# or Python), but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace as below:

```
System.out.println("before " + json + " after " + json.replace("\\", ""));
```

Output is:

```
before String json = \"key\":valuea\/b"; after String json = "key":valuea/b";
```